# How to store 2 dependent values into an array?

Tags: php

I want to store 2 dependent values in this array:

> ["STEP5"]=>   array(1) {
>       ["OPTIONS"]=>
>       array(2) {
>         [0]=>
>         string(4) "opt2"
>         [1]=>
>         string(4) "opt3"
>       }   }

Option fields (**opt1**, **opt2**,...) can have an extra field **input**. So how to store that in my array ? Thanx a lot.

Comment: You might want to look at creating an XML or a JSON instead of multi-layered arrays

Comment: what about muti-dimension array!

Answer (score 0):

You make each element of the `OPTIONS` array into an array itself. This would be better illustrated as:

```
["STEP5"] => array(1) {
    ["OPTIONS"] => array(2) {
        [0] => array(2) {
            ["TEXT"] => "opt2"
            ["INPUT"] => "input data"
        }
        [1] => array(1) {
            ["TEXT"] => "opt3"
            // No input data here
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can access the fields as:

```
$foo["STEP5"]["OPTIONS"][0]["TEXT"]
$foo["STEP5"]["OPTIONS"][0]["INPUT"]
$foo["STEP5"]["OPTIONS"][1]["TEXT"]
```

You don't have to have the "INPUT" field for every single option, but you can add it if you need to. Also, you might consider using objects to accomplish this task as they provide lots of useful functionality.